# How to automatically recover from network errors on Apollo Client?

Tags: express, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I have an application that my organization uses to display data. The app uses React, express, Apollo Server and Apollo Client. The app displays data from multiple sources and uses a polling method to to update the data. The problem comes when I perform updates to the code and the front end ends up trying to perform a request for more data but server is temporarily unavailable (like 2 minutes or less while the build command updates the code). This results in all the dashboard components displaying a network error.

My question, is there a good solution to have the front end automatically recover so we don't have to refresh the dashboards after every update? For example keep polling instead of stopping on network errors?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [Apollo Link Retry](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/retry/) should do what you want. It will retry after network failures

Answer (score 1):

Attention! You have to work with multiple Apollo-Links then like using WebSocketLink, Http-Link and the Retry-Link the Retry-Link has to be the first Link in the Array of Apollo-Links. Otherwise it wont work.